# I would like to display different text on different pages

Tags: custom-field, widgets, customization

I have at the very top of my page a line of text within a h1 tag thet I use for seo reasons. the text and html around it is written in my header.php. but I would like to write differnet txt so it appears different on each page for seo reasons.
for example:

- homepage- line of text reads builders in lancaster, builders in morecambe etc
- plastereing page- line of text reads plasterers in lancaster, plasterers in morecambe etc
- roofing page - line of text reads roofing in lancaster, roofing in morecambe etc

I know there is the Widget Logic Plugin but that's for widgets and not the main header.php. Is there a line of code I can write in header.php to do what the widget logic would do.

Comment: Which theme are you using? Why not use the page title for it?

Answer (score 0):

Of course, use this: http://codex.wordpress.org/Conditional_Tags#A_PAGE_Page

Example:

```
if(is_page('Contact Us')){
//contact us h1...
}
else....
```